# foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed laravel

Tags: database, laravel, migration

When I want to migrate my migration with `migrate` and `migrate:fresh` commands I'm getting [This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juG9h.jpg)

And These are my migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('card_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('card_id')->references('id')->on('card')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I just tried anything, I don't know what should I do more [I'm a beginner in laravel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your notes table is being created before your users table, hence the foreign key error. It can's find the users table because it doesn't exist (yet)

Laravel migrates in order, so there are 2 hacks to fix this:

1. Change the timestamp on the users migration file so it executes first
2. A more common hack is to have a seperate migration entirely for foreign key relationships. Then change the timestamp so it executes last. This way you know all your tables will exist by the time you execute the fk migration

Comment: no problem. could you please mark as the accepted answer and upvote . Cheers! happy coding ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change date and time in migrations files, so `cards` and `users` tables were created before `notes` table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure `cards` and `users` are created before `notes`.

In addition instead of:

```
$table->foreign('card_id')->references('id')->on('card')->onDelete('cascade');
```

use:

```
$table->foreign('card_id')->references('id')->on('cards')->onDelete('cascade');
```

(you have `card` instead of `cards`)